# How to used the e.SelectedControl from the Devexpress Tooltip event

Tags: c#, devexpress

In the Devexpress `ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs` Event there is a parameter passed to the function.
There is a `SelectedControl` member variable which points to the DevEx grid control object.
From here I want can get the active `GridView` (this is because I have several grids coming in here).
Can someone give me some sample code to get from the `SelectedControl` to the `GridView`?

```
private void MyToolTipController_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the view under the mouse point then you can use [`GridControl.GetViewAt`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_GetViewAttopic) method.
Here is example:

```
private void MyToolTipController_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
{
    var gridControl = e.SelectedControl as GridControl;

    if (gridControl != null)
    {
        var view = gridControl.GetViewAt(e.ControlMousePosition);

        //Your code here.
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to get the focused view then you can use [`GridControl.FocusedView`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_FocusedViewtopic) property.
Here is example:

```
private void MyToolTipController_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
{
    var gridControl = e.SelectedControl as GridControl;

    if (gridControl != null)
    {
        var view = gridControl.FocusedView;

        //Your code here.
    }
}
```